# Calling Model Data from View Outside Model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call data from a `ClubFitting` model on my `users#show` page and am having difficulty.  I have checked that data is saving correctly in my database and it is, so I know it's just a matter of calling it from the view.

I have this in my `users_controller`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @full_swing = ClubFitting.where(user: current_user, club_type: "Full Swing")
    @wedge = ClubFitting.where(user: current_user, club_type: "Wedge")
    @putter = ClubFitting.where(user: current_user, club_type: "Putter")
    unless current_user && (current_user.admin || @user == current_user)
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have access to that page."
    end
  end
end
```

In my view I'm trying to call data like this (`model` is one of the columns in `FullSwing`):

```
        <% if @full_swing %>
          <p><strong>Model:</strong> <%= @full_swing.model %></p>
          <%= link_to "Retest", fitting_full_path %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to "Get Full Swing Club Recommendation", fitting_full_path %>
        <% end %>
```

But instead of getting something like "Model: G" (as it should be based on the database value of that `user`'s `FullSwing.model`) I'm getting "Model: FullSwing" on my view.

Can anyone help me get this right?

Comment: Is `model` a field of `ClubFitting`?

Comment: @RSB, hello again.  `Model` is one of the columns in `ClubFitting`, yes.  (The `ClubFitting` table consists of columns named `model`, `length`, etc.)

Comment: Ok and the relation between `User` and `ClubFitting` is `user has_many club_fittings` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.first` after `where()` because `where()` returns a collection of the model, do this

```
@full_swing = ClubFitting.where(user: current_user, club_type: "Full Swing").first
@wedge = ClubFitting.where(user: current_user, club_type: "Wedge").first
@putter = ClubFitting.where(user: current_user, club_type: "Putter").first
```

Alternatively, I would suggest you to use `find_by` instead

```
@full_swing = ClubFitting.find_by(user: current_user, club_type: "Full Swing")
@wedge = ClubFitting.find_by(user: current_user, club_type: "Wedge")
@putter = ClubFitting.find_by(user: current_user, club_type: "Putter")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That definitely made variables show up (thank goodness), but now the one for `wedge` shows the data for the first `ClubFitting` submitted, even though the `club_type` was "Full Swing" not "Wedge".  Thoughts?

Comment: Aaah, no, I forgot to change it!  This is perfect!  Thank you.  Why did that work?

Comment: Glad that helped! `where` returns a collection of the model, and `model` is an `ActiveRecord` method that returns class name, thats why  you were getting `FullSwing` because thats your class name. `collection` is kind of an array of objects, so you need to call `first` to fetch the first object.

Comment: Okay, last question.  This changes the results of some logic I had on the `users#show` page that said `<% if @full_swing != [] %>` I tried `<% if @full_swing != nil %>` but that didn't work right either.  What is it now?

Comment: Okay, you can try this `<% if @full_swing.present? %>`

Comment: Ahhh, better.  Thank you!